# How to modify body styles based on localStorage for NextJS application before Hydration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

If you go to [React](https://react.dev) and toggle the theme. Your choice is stored in localStorage. If you refresh the page, the theme persists.

In my NextJS application, I am trying to achieve the same result by adding styles to the body element if a value in local storage exists. However, the styles are only added once the page has rendered. Therefore, there is a noticible lag before the styles are applied. I am wondering if there is a way to add styles to the body element based on local storage before the page renders and/or best practices for this use case.

What I have tried:

```
"use client"
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"

export const DarkThemeContext = createContext()

const DarkThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("darkTheme")) setDarkTheme(true)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (darkTheme) {
      document.body.classList.add("dark-theme")
      localStorage.setItem("darkTheme", JSON.stringify(true))
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("dark-theme")
      localStorage.removeItem("darkTheme")
    }
  }, [darkTheme])

  return (
    <DarkThemeContext.Provider value={{ darkTheme, setDarkTheme }}>
      {children}
    </DarkThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default DarkThemeProvider
```

Then imported the DarkThemeProvider into the RootLayout component:

```
import Header from "./_components/Header/Header"
import DarkThemeProvider from "./_context/DarkThemeProvider"
import "./_styles/_globals.scss"

export const metadata = {
  title: "NextJS",
  description: "Generated by Next.js",
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <DarkThemeProvider>
          <Header />
          <main className="main">{children}</main>
        </DarkThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

I thought the lag was caused by the fact I'm adding styles to the body with useEffect, which runs after the components have rendered.

I then tried:

```
import Script from "next/script"
import Header from "./_components/Header/Header"
import DarkThemeProvider from "./_context/DarkThemeProvider"
import "./_styles/_globals.scss"

export const metadata = {
  title: "NextJS",
  description: "Generated by Next.js",
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Script id="theme-script">
          {`if (localStorage.getItem("darkTheme")) {
          document.body.classList.add("dark-theme")
          localStorage.setItem("darkTheme", JSON.stringify(true))
        } else {
          document.body.classList.remove("dark-theme")
          localStorage.removeItem("darkTheme")
        }`}
        </Script>
        <DarkThemeProvider>
          <Header />
          <main className="main">{children}</main>
        </DarkThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

without the useEffects in the DarkThemeProvider.

There is still a lag adding styles to the body element. I can also visualise this in the elements tab in the browser's dev tools. The dark theme class is added to the body after the page has rendered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use [next-themes](https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes) that handles your case very well.

### Install

```bash
$ npm install next-themes
```

### Use

Wrap your app in `<ThemeProvider>`

```js
// app/providers.jsx

'use client'

import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes'

export function Providers({ children }) {
  return <ThemeProvider>{children}</ThemeProvider>
}
```

```js
// app/layout.jsx

import { Providers } from './providers'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html suppressHydrationWarning>
      <head />
      <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

To access the theme you can use `useTheme` hook

```js
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes'

const ThemeChanger = () => {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme()

  return (
    <div>
      The current theme is: {theme}
      <button onClick={() => setTheme('light')}>Light Mode</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTheme('dark')}>Dark Mode</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```